# .value Returning Nothing (javaScript)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the value of the phone number from a contact, but I either get [object, Object] returned to me or nothing at all. When I try matches[i].phoneNumbers I get [object, Object] and when I add matches[i].phoneNumbers[0].value, my alert stops altogether.

```
function callme() {
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter = ""; //leaving this empty will find return all contacts
    options.multiple = true; //return multiple results
    console.log(options);
    var filter = ["displayName", "phoneNumbers"]; //an array of fields to compare against the options.filter 

    navigator.contacts.find(filter, successFunc, errFunc, options);

    function successFunc(matches) {
        for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
            //this loops through all of the contacts

            var contact_name = matches[i].displayName;
            var contact_number = matches[i].phoneNumbers; //this returns [object, Object]
            // var contact_number = matches[i].phoneNumbers[0].value; returns nothing at all
            var contact_full = contact_name + " " + contact_number;
        }
        alert(contact_full);
    }

    function errFunc() {
        alert("oh no!");
    }
};
```

Comment: [Learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) and use `console.log` instead of `alert`.

Comment: Why not dumb out matches[i] with console.log(matches[i]) and see if value is a property of matches

Comment: I can't use console.log as I am testing this on a phone.

Comment: What kind of phone? If it's an iPhone, you can connect it to the Safari developer tools on your Mac. There might be something similar for Android phones. And depending on what exactly you are developing, you could first test/build your app on a desktop.

Comment: Add this to your app to see if it alerts the number.

`if(matches[i].phoneNumbers){
   alert(contact_number[0].phoneNumbers[0].value);
}`

Comment: I am using a android phone, and I am using the phone's contacts so I can't test in on my desktop. I am also using an emulator, but it's very glitchy.

Comment: The if(matches[i].phoneNumbers){    alert(contact_number[0].phoneNumbers[0].value); } doesn't alert anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the structure of your JSON Objects are but you can debug in firebug and if your not sure how to do that, then just try the following below:

```
function successFunc(matches) {
        for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
            //this loops through all of the contacts

        var contact_name = matches[i].displayName;
        alert(JSON.stringify(matches[i].phoneNumbers);
var contact_number = matches[i].phoneNumbers; //this returns [object, Object]
            // var contact_number = matches[i].phoneNumbers[0].value; returns nothing at all
            var contact_full = contact_name + " " + contact_number;

    }
    alert(contact_full);
}
```

You'll be able to see the property list of the object once the alert dialog comes up.

Comment: This is what I get in the alert: [{"type":"mobile","value":"1-555-555-5555","id":"1","pref":false}]

Comment: Try this matches[i].phoneNumbers[0]["value"]